# Redirect subdomain to hidden folder using mod_rewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite, subdomain

I want to keep my blog in subfolder `domain_com/htdocs/blog`
and access it using blog.domain.com. I can obtain it using apache's mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.domain\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^/blog
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /blog/$1 [L]
```

But I also want to redirect hxxp://domain.com/blog to hxxp://blog.domain.com (simply because I want to hide it from users). Simple redirection like:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^wojtyniak\.com$
RewriteRule %{REQUEST_URI} ^/foo
RewriteRule ^(.*)$      http://foo.wojtyniak.com  [L,R=301]
```

causes redirection loop. Is there any way to make such a redirection without loop?
Big thanks!

PS. Sorry for those hxxp thing, but serverfault thinks these are link and doesn't allow me to post more than one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most ideal solution would be to put this on a virtual-host, with the blog files hosted somewhere outside of your htdocs directory.

I'm going to assume that you won't have access to make these necessary changes, but in case you do, [here's the documentation for it](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/examples.html).

Comment: Unfortunately I can't create new vhost:(

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I know. Noone will need this anymore here, after 2 years. But maybe someone who is redirected here by Google.

```
# Rewrite <subdomain>.example.com/<path> to example.com/<subdomain>/<path>
#
# Skip rewrite if no hostname or if subdomain is www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
# Extract (required) subdomain (%1), and first path element (%3), discard port number if present (%2)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}<>%{REQUEST_URI} ^([^.]+)\.example\.com(:80)?<>/([^/]*) [NC]
# Rewrite only when subdomain not equal to first path element (prevents mod_rewrite recursion)
RewriteCond %1<>%3 !^(.*)<>\1$ [NC]
# Rewrite to /subdomain/path
RewriteRule ^(.*) /%1/$1 [L]
```

#

I found that here http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum92/1310.htm